# Facing 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, linux, unix, url, cpanel

I am getting 403 Forbidden Error while i am access images from the server.

If I access audio file then i am not getting any error.
but if i am accessing image file then only i am facing this issue.

Please note that the permission of audio file is 0644 and also permission of images have same permission 0644

Please check below images of Path and URL

[PAth of images on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Upf.png)

[URL of image which i am accessing from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4npWT.png)

Comment: For me it's working check the link 


  http://i.stack.imgur.com/SRhlx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That's work For me

But when I access http://scriptlogsolution.com/ganesha/images/
I get this error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnYCV.png)

I think, You access the directory link.